# dynamoDB query: SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE userId IN myList

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I'm migrating mySQL to DynamoDB. In mySQL, I have

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE userId IN myList
```

How can I achieve it in DynamoDB?

Thanks

Comment: Userid is a normal attribute or defined as hash or sort key of dynamodb table?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [filter expression](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.SpecifyingConditions.html#ConditionExpressionReference) on a [Scan](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html) operation to achieve the same result as the SQL query above. For example, if you use the Document SDK in Java, you could write the following:

```
final Table table = new Table(AmazonDynamoDBClient.builder().withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build(), "mytable");
//convert the Iterable<Item> returned by table.scan() to a stream of Items
StreamSupport.stream(
        // list however many items you need to test after IN
        table.scan(new ScanSpec().withFilterExpression("userId IN :u1, :u2")
                //define the values of the set of usernames you are testing in the list avove
                .withValueMap(ImmutableMap.of(":u1", "robert", ":u2", "daniel"))).spliterator(), false)
        //do useful stuff with the result set
        .map(Item::toJSONPretty)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```